# Error in the translation of sentences (RYandexTranslate R package)

Tags: r, json

I'm developing a program with RStudio.
I try to translate sentences with the RYandexTranslate R package. (free solution)
The API Yandex can translate words but when I try to detect language or to translate  sentences, I have an error :

```
dtct.char <- detect_language(api_key, text=text.char)
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <html>  <head><title>400 Bad Re
                 (right here) ------^
trad.char <- translate(api_key, text = text.char, lang = lang.char)[2]
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <html>  <head><title>400 Bad Re
                 (right here) ------^
```

My code :

```
install.packages("RYandexTranslate")
library("RYandexTranslate")
api_key ="My Key"
text.char <- "Bonjour, comment vas tu ?"
dtct.char <- detect_language(api_key, text=text.char)
lang.char <- paste(detect.lang,"-en",sep="")
trad.char <- translate(api_key, text = text.char, lang = lang.char)[2]
```

Someone can help me please ? 
I can't progress with this error. 
Thank you a lot.

PS: If I try directly to translate a sentence like this :

```
translate(api_key, text = "Bonjour, comment vas tu ?", lang = "fr-en")
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   <html>  <head><title>400 Bad Re
                 (right here) ------^
```

The problem is always here.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious, signed up for the site and got an API key to test it out. I can reproduce your error, and it seems to be related to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mukul13/RYandexTranslate/issues/2), which has not been followed up with a package update.

Jacques Peeters has posted a working alternative at this issue---I am just copy-pasting.

```
translate = function (api_key, text = "", lang = "") 
{
  url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?"
  url = paste(url, "key=", api_key, sep = "")
  if (text != "") {
    url = paste(url, "&text=", text, sep = "")
  }
  if (lang != "") {
    url = paste(url, "&lang=", lang, sep = "")
  }
  url = gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "%20", x = url)
  d = RCurl::getURL(url, ssl.verifyhost = 0L, ssl.verifypeer = 0L)
  d = jsonlite::fromJSON(d)
  d$code = NULL
  d
}
```

I have verified that this works with an example from the manual:

```
> translate(api_key,text="how are you?",lang="en-hi"  )
$lang
[1] "en-hi"
$text
[1] "आप कैसे हैं?"
```

Hope this helps.